# How can I set a special character as a textview text

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to set '@' as a text inside a `TextView`, but since `@` is a reference key, it won't allow me to set it as text.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it like this `\\@` for resources like this `<string name="my_string">\\@my_string</string`and `\@` between double quotes

Comment: yes, in your case because you are using it between double quotes, just FYI for something like a resource you should use it with double backslash like so  `<string name="my_string">\\@my_string</string>` I'll edit the answer

Comment: how add this character --> "

Answer (score 2):

```
 string str = "&#8804;  &#8805;";

 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

or you can also use this

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TableRow>    
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="•"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="First line"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>    
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="•"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Second line"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\@` to get the character you need.